# How to remove an Element List null on Simpleframework XML

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I'm using SimpleFramework in order to create a XML. Everything works fine, expect one "little" thing. When one of my lists are empty, SimpleFramework keekps adding the tag of the list (empty, of course). How can I tell Simpleframework not to add the empty tag when it's null or has size == 0 ?

XML Class:

```
@Root(name="title")
public class XML {
    @ElementList(name="tags", inline=true, required=false, empty=true)
    @Path("tags")
    private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

Tag class:

```
    @Root(name="tag")
    public class Tag {
            @Text
            private String name;
     }
```

When the list is empty:

Generated output:

```
<xml>
   <tags/>
   <otherTag>1</otherTag>
   <otherTag>2</otherTag>
</xml>
```

Expected output:

```
<xml>
   <otherTag>1</otherTag>
   <otherTag>2</otherTag>
</xml>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `Path` annotation on `tags` property and try:

```
@ElementList(name="tags", inline=true, required=false, empty=true)
//@Path("tags")
private List<Tag> tags;
```